# what are location and uri in zend client non-wsdl

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-framework2

I used to make soap client in *wsdl* mode this way:

```
use Zend\Soap\Client;
$client = new \SoapClient('www.foo.com/api?wsdl');
```

and everything went good. Now I'm asked to use non-wsdl mode and given *wsdl.xml* file.
To make it work. have to set up location and uri options. Can anyone explain what are these two options stand for and how to use them in my case??

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Can it be in wsdl mode using this file??